# Como converter um projeto Maven para Gradlew?

Tags: java, maven, gradle

Tenho um projeto em maven funciando perfeitamente e preciso converter para Gradlew de que forma posso fazer isso ?

Comment: Não concordo que esta pergunta seja "fora de escopo".

Comment: A primeira coisa a se fazer é um `gradle init`. O gradle irá ler o pom.xml do maven e gerar um build.gradle compatível. Porém, há coisas que não são migradas (como plugins, tasks customizadas), e precisam ser ajustados manualmente. Veja um manual completo sobre a conversão em https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/migrating_from_maven.html

Comment: Estou tendo dificuldade em migra a biblioteca  org.jrimum.bopepo para o projeto Gradlew